# Modified tangent function

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I remember reading once of a modified arctangent function which was suited to be a chart on the circle. It should be defined something like

$$\theta(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) & x>0\\
\pi/2 & (x,y)=(0,1)\\
-\pi/2 & (x,y)=(0,-1)\\
\pi+\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) & x<0, y>0\\
-\pi+\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) & x<0, y<0
\end{cases}$$

Can somebody remind me of its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be known as $atan2(y,x)$ (the two-argument arctangent function).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2